# What to do when led #3 & #5 don't lite up in cable tester

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable, cat6, terminator

I have clamped my 1st network cable. It's a "Vega network cable FTP CAT6 4PR 23AWG TIA/EIA-568B ISO/IEC 11801 2017" cable. It's in my house (inside the walls) between 2 floors, installed (inside the wall) by my electrician 5 years ago, when the house was built. I clamped the 2 terminators today. I used a friend's cable tester "Master NSHL468". I tested the tester with a known good cable, and it works, but with my cable LEDs #3 and #5 don't lite up. I was hoping that at least I can get some slow speeds with it, but there's no network at all.

How should I proceed?

I'll add that there is another cable in the wall between the same 2 points, and at first I was trying to locate which cable is which to know which cable ends to clamp. I used an AA battery connected to wires blue and orange (randomly chosen) and a LED connected to the same wires on the other end of the cables, but the LED did not lite up with any of the cables. Then I connected the battery to the other cable and I was able to find the other end of that cable, and then I clamped the terminators. I am telling this, because I have a feeling that the electrician might have damaged some of the wires in the cables.

If that was the case, and I was able to identify the 2 broken wires, then would I be able to clamp 2 new terminators with a specific wire order to make sure that the correct wires are in the places that will enable to use the cable with slower speeds until I manage to replace the cables? (Won't be easy I guess, these 2 cables did not budge when I tried to pull on them in order to identify the other end of the cable, and I remember the electrician telling me that there were numerous (electrical) cables that gave him a hard time to install because of problems with the channels in the wall)

Or let's be more optimistic: what's the chance that the problem is not with the cable but with my clamping? It was not easy to clamp them, I guess partially because this was the 1st time I did it, and probably also because this cable is very hard, not like the few meters short and soft cables we use in the office between the wall socket and the computer.

Comment: Can you borrow another cable tester for side by side comparison?   I have a cable tester and all 8 lights tun on for a good cable.

Comment: It's not clear when you tested with the battery.  Is it possible that your `clamping` of connectors has not gone well?

Comment: The tester works, as I wrote I tested it with a good cable and all 8 LEDs worked.

Comment: Yes it's very possible (and that is my hope, because then asking my friend to clamp 2 new terminators could fix the problem) that I screwed up the clamping.

Comment: Hard and soft is likely 'stranded' vs solid cable. And generally solid  cable is used in walls and with keystones and stranded is what you'd use for the last bit.

Answer (score 2):

I cut both terminators, and checked each wire pair with battery and LED and all worked, so it was caused by my clamping.

Because the cable is this hard wire that is used for the wall it's not really made for these terminators (I'm not sure if there are terminators that are good for this cable) so I used 2 keystone connectors on both ends and then a 1m network cable (already had them) to connect to the switch and the network extender in the attic.

Comment: Doing your own terminations tends to need a bit of practice, even with the correct type of cable

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to basically split it.  A cat6 cable can be split into two at either end.  You can buy standard connectors for it.  The maximum speed is reduced a lot.  But that is better than getting errors and retries.

Use any coloured pairs you like (it's best to follow the standard) and connect them to pins 1,2,3,6 at both ends.

- 1 Wh-Br
- 2 Br
- 3 Wh-Bl
- 6 Bl

OR

- 1 Wh-Gr
- 2 Gr
- 3 Wh-Or
- 6 Or

[image]

Image from https://www.tillescenter.org/.  I have no association with the site.

Disclaimer, I haven't done this manually, I have used the splitters.  But I think it will work.

Comment: OK this at least explains why it didn't work: because I had 2 LEDS that didn't lite up: 3 and 5, so both halves had 1 wire that wasn't connected correctly.

Comment: The maximum speed isn't halved, as Gigabit Ethernet doesn't have an option to work with fewer lanes; it's outright reduced to 100 Mbps (which is a 1/10x reduction). You can't exactly use "any" wires you like – you can choose any colors but you cannot break up pairs; *that* would definitely give you errors and retries. Make sure 1-2 and 3-6 remain twisted pairs (exactly as if wiring a standard 10/100M connector).